# Why does :latest aspnet core docker image run when the tag :1.1 fails?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I created an ASP.NET Core solution with Visual Studio 2017, adding docker support on creation. The docker file in the project is:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AspNetCoreInDocker.dll"]
```

When I run the project, it builds OK but then I get an error:

[image: Net Core did not start]

In the debug output I have:

```
realpath(): Invalid argument
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at: /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
  1.1.1
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.2'.
The program '' has exited with code 131 (0x83).
```

I appreciate the solution is "install 1.1.2" but that's the not my problem. If I change the first line of the docker file to use the `:latest` tag:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:latest
```

Then it builds and runs fine.

On the docker hub page for [microsoft/aspnetcore](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/) the tags both point to the same location: https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/blob/master/1.1/jessie/runtime/Dockerfile

I would expect both tags to fail. Why would `:1.1` fail and `:latest` run?

Answer (score 0):

Check version of dotnet in your container with

```
docker exec -ti container_name bash
dotnet --version
```

Comment: How does that answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is docker caching.  You specified 1.1, and when you built the image the first time that meant 1.1.1.   Now docker is always giving you 1.1.1 from the cache when specifying 1.1 in the Dockerfile.